# How to display the name of the user after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I'm new in React and just manage to make to login and registration page with JWT and MySQL, but now I would like the name of the user to appear when the user is logged in. Can someone help me? I shared my login and register component. I thought that I could that by adding something like

Welcome{props.name}

on a different component but it's not working.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    login = () => {

        const { email, password} = this.state;

        axios("/users/login", {
            method: "POST",
            data:{
                email, 
                password,
            }
        }).then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            this.props.history.push("/track");
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            
            
<div>
           
            <div className="login-container">
                <input 
                className="mb-3" 
                type="text"
                name="email"
                value={this.state.email}
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={this.handleChange} /><br></br>

                <input 
                className="mb-3" 
                type="password" 
                name="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={this.handleChange} /><br></br>

                <button className="login-button" onClick={this.login  }>Sign in</button>
                <p className="text-white mt-2">Not a member? <Link to="/register" className="text-black">Register</Link></p>
            </div>
             </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           users: [],
           name: "",
           email: "",
           password: "",
           confirmpassword : ""
           
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUsers();
    }

    getUsers = () => {
        fetch(`users`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ users: response })
        })
    }

    addUsers = () => {
        const { name, email, password, confirmpassword } = this.state;
        fetch(`/users`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({name, email, password, confirmpassword}),
        })
    
            .then((response) => response.json())
          
            .then(response => console.log(response.msg))
            this.props.history.push("/login");
 
    }
    

    handleInput = (e)  => {
        const { value, name } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });

    }
    render() {
        const {name, email, password, confirmpassword} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="cover d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

           
<div className="text-center login-container">
   
    <input 
    className="mb-3" 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Full name"
    name="name"
    value={name}
    onChange={this.handleInput} /><br></br>

    <input 
    className="mb-3" 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Email"
    name="email"
    value={email}
    onChange={this.handleInput} /><br></br>

    <input 
    className="mb-3" 
    type="password" 
    placeholder="Password"
    name="password"
    value={password}
    onChange={this.handleInput}/><br></br>

    <input 
    className="mb-3" 
    type="password" 
    placeholder="Confirm Password"
    name="confirmpassword"
    value={confirmpassword}
    onChange={this.handleInput}/><br></br>

    <button className="signup-button" onClick={this.addUsers}>Sign up</button>

</div>
 </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use props to display the user's name, you will have to pass the `name` prop from the parent component. But, you will first need to get the user's name from your server. Your code may look like the following.

Parent component:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

const getUserName = () => {
 axios('/path/to/user/endpoint', {
  method: 'get'
 })
 .then(response => {
   this.setState({name: response.data.name})
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
 })
};

render(
 <Track name={this.state.name} />
);

}
```

Instead of passing a the name prop from a parent component as shown above, you might want to fetch the data from the server after routing to `/track`. If you choose to go with this method, you can reuse the `getUserName` function shown in the last example.

Lastly, if you want to use the user's name globally, you might want to invest some time in learning a library such as Redux, so that you can use a global state.

Comment: Can  I not use localStorage instead of redux to do that ?